# Why can't I initialize a property onCreateViewHolder in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I initialize the property `mListMy` in `onCreateViewHolder` event, but I get the error

*lateinit property mListMy has not been initialized*

How can I fix it?

**Code**

```
class MydAdapter () : RecyclerView.Adapter<MydAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

   private lateinit var mListMy: List<MRecord>

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MydAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        initListMy()

        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview_my, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    fun initListMy(){
        mListMy=RecordHandler().listAllRecord(ESortBy.NameAsc,ECategory.My)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MydAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(mListMy[position])
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For initialization of property you can use `init` block of kotlin. Which is called after the constructor call.

```
class MydAdapter () : RecyclerView.Adapter<MydAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var mListMy: List<MRecord>

    init {
        initListMy()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MydAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview_my, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    fun initListMy(){
        mListMy=RecordHandler().listAllRecord(ESortBy.NameAsc,ECategory.My)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MydAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(mListMy[position])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin `lateinit` modifier  not allowed properties with initilizer.
`lateinit` means you will assign the value for that variable later not in initilizer.

for these case you can use normal `var`. otherwise  it should be constructor like this

```
class MydAdapter (va1 mListMy:List<YourDatamodel> ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MydAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {



override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MydAdapter.MyViewHolder {

    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview_my, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(v)
}



override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MydAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItems(mListMy[position])
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! but your code doesn't work, it seems that  mListMy need to be initilize before the event `onCreateViewHolder` .

Comment: for this case it should be constructor.check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize your list in constructor, look at the line below:

```
class MydAdapter (val mListMy:List<YourDatamodel> = listOf() ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MydAdapter.MyViewHolder>()
// rest of your code
```

That way you can call your adapter without initialize your list because it is already initialized with a default value (an empty list).

Comment: Thanks! Is there  a better way? my current class is `class MydAdapter ()`, and your class is `class MydAdapter (val mListMy:List<YourDatamodel> = listOf() )`